# Sending mails using pure nodejs code

Tags: node.js, http, email

I want to establish a node server that takes data from a client and send them using e-mail.

This question may be duplicate but the real problem is that I searched but all I found were modules and libraries that help me to do so.

That may be the real problem that obstructs me in learning nodejs because sources offering pure nodejs learning is very little (As if nodejs consists of express only!)

I don't want to use a library or a module, I want to use pure nodejs code to do so.

What is the mechanism that I have to use to do so using pure nodejs, maybe the request method of http module or the net module have a way to do that but I can't think how!

Comment: You should reconsider what you mean by 'pure node.js' - eg., you will be hard-pressed to solve any interesting problem without using one of the built-in modules.

Have a look at some texts on the philosophy of node.js, like [this very terse one](https://javascriptreport.com/node-js-philosopy/) or [this more elaborate essay](http://thenodeway.io/introduction/).

Modules are your friend, and a large part of effective node.js programming means finding apt modules, reviewing and interfacing them. You'll still have ample opportunity at writing own code and learning about node design principles.

Comment: using pure node means exactly using the core modules 
such as fs or http not modules installed by npm,
that's what everybody know about the meaning of 'pure node' and it doesn't need redefining

Comment: In general, I hate to use frameworks or libraries without knowing how to use native code

Comment: Good luck then in rigorously defining the difference between npm-hosted and core modules, with the set of the latter and their APIs constantly changing (eg. Async_hooks, available as core module with v8; URL with 7; Buffer experiencing major API changes in 6). Just out of interest: do you consider the STL of c++ a library or part of the core ? Learning to code idiomatically imho is very orthogonal to the use of frameworks/libraries. Addressing your original question, consult standards on the SMTP/IMAP protocol and use the `Net` module to listen to the client / talk to the mail server .